# Insert Raster to MXD using arcpy.mapping (ArcGIS 10)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, raster, arcpy

What i want to do seems simple. But again i can't even find a workaround...

I have got a lot of Raster-files (ESRI-GRID) which i need to insert into a layout mxd-file and then export the map to PDF/JPEG/whatever.

The Final  Export in Python is no Problem. 
But how do I insert/replace a Raster in the mxd file?
It has to be something like:

```
fcs = gp.ListRasters("*", "GRID")
for fc in fcs:
    [change Raster (/ Raster Data Source?)]
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, "D:\\test.pdf")
```

I Hope that anybody has an idea :)
Thanks for your help!
Markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script that I used for changing all the sources in a map document from an SDE raster catalogs to raster mosaics. This could hopefully be a good lead for what you are trying to do. Notice that I pre-built the .lyr files and stored them in a specific location. You can use artwork21's method to automatically create .lyr files too instead of prebuilding.

```
import arcpy
path = u'sample' #Our internal path to the mosaic directory. Removed from this sample.
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") #You can also have this go to a specific mxd
print "Updating Aerial Catalogs to Aerial Mosaics..."
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for refLayer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*.AERIAL_*", df):
                year = refLayer.dataSource[-4:] #This is based on our naming convention, AERIAL_YYYY
                print  u'Updating AERIAL_' + year + u' to Mosaic....
                if year == u'1970':
                        year = u'1970_72'
                if year == u'1997':
                        year = u'1995_97'
                name = u'Mosaic_' + year + u'.lyr'
                mosaic = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path + name) #Making a new layer
                arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, mosaic, "BEFORE") #Insert the layer in front of the layer I am replacing
                mosaic.visible = refLayer.visible #Copying across all the attributes on the old layer
                mosaic.brightness = refLayer.brightness
                mosaic.contrast = refLayer.contrast
                mosaic.transparency = refLayer.transparency
                mosaic.name = refLayer.name
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, refLayer) #Take out the old raster layer
                print name + u' updated.'
arcpy.RefreshActiveView() #Not needed if you are not working on an open document
arcpy.RefreshTOC() #Not needed if you are not working on an open document
del mxd, df
try:
        del refLayer, year, name, path, mosaic #Do your cleanup properly
except:
        pass
finally:
        print u'All Mosaics updated!'
```

I have a much more complicated version of this that spiders through a drive and changes -every- mxd on the drive too, if that is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Save you raster as a layer file first, then you can use the [AddLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000025000000.htm) option.  Below is a link to a parallel question to yours.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/22835-Loading-a-raster-into-a-dataframe-in-arcpy

**Update:**

Here is how you can save a raster to a lyr in python:

```
  # Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

# Local variables...
Aerial_0622_tif_lyr = "C:\\Temp\\Aerial_0622.tif.lyr"
Aerial_06_tif = "Aerial_06.tif"

# Process: Save To Layer File...
gp.SaveToLayerFile_management(Aerial_06_tif, Aerial_0622_tif_lyr)
```

Comment: but how can i save a raster as a layer file in python?

Comment: @Markus, I update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, thanks to @blord-castillo and @artwork21 this is the final script that has worked for me!!

```
import arcpy, os, string, logging, datetime
from arcpy import env



path = "E:\\mappingtest\\raster\\" #Path to Raster
outPDFpath = "E:\\mappingtest\\out.pdf" #final PDF Output
env.workspace=path
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("E:\\mappingtest\\mxddtet.mxd") 
outputPDF = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(outPDFpath)
sourceLayer=arcpy.mapping.Layer("E:\\mappingtest\\raster\\update.lyr")


fcs = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "GRID")

x=0
for fc in fcs:
    fc_lyr=path + fc[:-1] + str(x) +"_temp.lyr" 
    fc_pluspath=path + fc
    fc_rl_temp=fc+"tp"

    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for refLayer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*[insert-keyword]*", df):
            arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(fc_pluspath, fc_rl_temp, "#", "", "#") 
            arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(fc_rl_temp, fc_lyr)
            lyr_file = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fc_lyr)
            arcpy.mapping.InsertLayer(df, refLayer, lyr_file, "BEFORE") # Insert New
            arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr_file, sourceLayer, "TRUE") # Update Symbology with example lyr-file
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, refLayer) # Remove Old
    PDFPath = path[:-4] + str(x) + "_temp.pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, PDFPath)
    outputPDF.appendPages(str(PDFPath))
    x=x+1
outputPDF.saveAndClose()
```